# head-tail subdivision of list not working with capital letters

Tags: elixir

I'm just starting to look at Elixir, and I've done a little *Scheme* and *Prolog* in the past.

I was fiddling in **iex**, and I simply wanted to see if it was possible to separate the head and the tail of a list in Elixir, like you would do in Scheme for example.

So I tried this, which was my habit for head & tail names:

```
[H|T] = [2,4,6,8]
```

However, it throws an error:

```
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: [9, 8, 4, 2]
```

I then tried:

```
[h|t] = [2,4,6,8]
```

and it worked as expected.

Why is this happening? Is there a special trait to variables starting with a capital letter? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Identifiers starting with a capital letter are not variables but atoms. `H` is equivalent to the atom `Elixir.H`:

```
iex(1)> H == :"Elixir.H"
true
```

So your code is equivalent to:

```
[:"Elixir.H" | :"Elixir.T"] = [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

which obviously fails as `:"Elixir.H" != 2`  and `:"Elixir.T" != [4, 6, 8]`.